# Select and deselect reusable views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I create a custom view in xib file. I add 3 views(which inherited from custom) in `viewController`. Initially they have white color, but when i click on first view it should be changed other color and if i click on second view, the first view should be back in white color.

I need help to change first view color back to white when second view is selected.

**My code for customView here**

```
class SubscriptionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMark: UIImageView!
    var isSelect: Bool = false

    let nibName = "SubscriptionView"
    var contentView: UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction)))
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else {
            return
        }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        view.layerBorderColor = AppColor.amaranth
        view.layerBorderWidth = 0.5
        self.addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

    public func selectedView(_ isSelect: Bool) {
        self.isSelect = isSelect
        title.textColor = isSelect ? UIColor.white : AppColor.amaranth
        subTitle.textColor = isSelect ? UIColor.white : AppColor.amaranth
        checkMark.alpha = isSelect ? 1.0 : 0.0
        contentView!.backgroundColor = isSelect ? AppColor.amaranth : UIColor.white
    }

    @objc private func tapAction() {
        ///????? selectedView

    }
}
```

Comment: you should have used tableview here , it is veryeasy  in tableview

Comment: Use Delegate / Protocol pattern. Your view controller assigns itself as your custom view's delegate. When you handle tap in your custom view, tell its delegate (the view controller) that it was tapped and let the view controller reset the other view(s) to white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example using the Delegate / Protocol pattern.

Define a Protocol:

```
// Protocol / Delegate pattern
protocol SubscriptionViewDelegate {
    func gotTap(from sender: SubscriptionView)
}
```

Have your view controller **conform** to that protocol. In your custom `SubscriptionView` class, when the user taps you will tell the **delegate** that a tap was received, and the controller will loop through the `SubscriptionView` objects setting the "selected" state to true or false, based on the tapped view.

```
class SubscriptionsViewController: UIViewController, SubscriptionViewDelegate {

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()

    // array to track the "subscription" views
    var arrayOfSubscriptionViews: [SubscriptionView] = [SubscriptionView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // add a stack view to hold the "subscription" views
        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            ])

        // instantiate 3 "subscription" views
        for _ in 1...3 {

            // instantiate view
            let v = SubscriptionView()

            // set self as its delegate
            v.delegate = self

            // add it to our stack view
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)

            // append it to our tracking array
            arrayOfSubscriptionViews.append(v)

        }

    }

    func gotTap(from sender: SubscriptionView) {

        // just for dev / debugging
        print("got tap from", sender)

        // loop through the subscription views,
        // setting the sender selected to TRUE
        // the others to FALSE

        arrayOfSubscriptionViews.forEach {
            $0.selectedView($0 == sender)
        }

    }

}

// Protocol / Delegate pattern
protocol SubscriptionViewDelegate {
    func gotTap(from sender: SubscriptionView)
}

class SubscriptionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMark: UIImageView!
    var isSelect: Bool = false

    var delegate: SubscriptionViewDelegate?

    let nibName = "SubscriptionView"
    var contentView: UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else {
            return
        }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // AppColor.amaranth
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.addSubview(view)
        contentView = view

        selectedView(false)

        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction)))
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

    public func selectedView(_ isSelect: Bool) {
        self.isSelect = isSelect
        title.textColor = isSelect ? UIColor.white : .red // AppColor.amaranth
        subTitle.textColor = isSelect ? UIColor.white : .red // AppColor.amaranth
        checkMark.alpha = isSelect ? 1.0 : 0.0
//      contentView!.backgroundColor = isSelect ? AppColor.amaranth : UIColor.white
        contentView!.backgroundColor = isSelect ? UIColor.red : UIColor.white
    }

    @objc private func tapAction() {

        // for dev / debugging
        print("sending tap from", self)

        // tell the delegate self got tapped
        delegate?.gotTap(from: self)

    }
}
```

I only made minor changes to your `SubscriptionView` class, so you should be able to use it as-is with your existing `.xib`

Comment: Thank you very much